# Prove that a field automorphism sends a root into a root

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I came across the following problem:

> If $E$ is an extension of $F$ and if $f(x)\in F[x]$ and if $\phi$ is an automorphism of $E$ leaving every element of $F$ fixed, prove that $\phi$ must take a root of $f(x)$ lying in $E$ into a root of $f(x)$ in $E$.

Here's what I have so far:

Let $a\in E$ be a root of $f(x)$. That is, $f(a)=0$. Define an automorphism $\phi: E \to E$ by $\phi(x)=x$. Trivially, the image of any root of $f(x)$ under $\phi$ is a root in the codomain $E$. That proves that the identity automorphism sends a root into a root.

I'm not sure what the other automorphisms are that I must consider. A hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All of the automorphisms. It doesn't matter what they are, just that they are automorphisms. Hint: $f(\phi(a))=\phi(f(a))$.

Comment: @anon Since $f(a)=0$, we have $f(\phi(a))=\phi(0)=0$. Does this imply that a root of $f(x)$ is mapped to a root of $f(x)$?

Comment: @anon Ah wait, I think I'm starting to see it. We have $f(\phi(a)) = c_0 + c_1\phi(a)+\cdots+c_n\phi(a^n) = 0$, so regardless of the choice of $\phi$, the image of $f(a)$ under $\phi$ is 0. Thus, for any root $a$, $\phi$ maps $a$ to a corresponding root in the codomain $E$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. If $f(a)=0$ (i.e. $a$ is a root of $f$) then $f(\phi(a))=c_0+c_1\phi(a)+\cdots=\phi(c_0+c_1a+\cdots)$ $=\phi(f(a))=\phi(0)=0$, or simply $f(\phi(a))=0$ i.e. $\phi(a)$ is a root of $f$ too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the case that $\phi$ is an *arbitrary* automorphism of $E$, such that for every $f \in F$, it is true that

$$\phi(f) = f$$

As a *hint* for the general case, write down a polynomial with coefficients in $F$; it looks like

$$f_n x^n + f_{n _ 1} x^{n - 1} + \dots + f_1 x + f_0$$

Now apply $\phi$ to this, using the above property.