# Field automorphisms send roots into roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

In the post [Prove that a field automorphism sends a root into a root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668861/prove-that-a-field-automorphism-sends-a-root-into-a-root), the following problem is discussed:

> If $E$ is an extension of $F$, $f(x) \in F[x]$ and $\phi$ is an automorphism of $E$ leaving every element of $F$ fixed, prove that $\phi$ must take a root of $f(x)$ lying in $E$ into a root of $f(x)$ in $E$.

I managed to solve it, using the argument described in the above post, but what I didn't see is where we used that $\phi$ is an **auto**-morphism. To me, it seems like it should work with any **endo**-morphism that fixes $F$. Is this true? If not, where were the hypothesis used in the proof of the above fact? And if it is indeed true, why is it?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the silly question!

Comment: Not a silly question. And you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you had an endomorphism that wasn't an isomorphism what might its kernel be?

Comment: The kernel can be $0$ without the image being $E$.

Comment: This shows that every endomorphism is injective or the $0$ function. But where does surjectivity come from?

Comment: @Gauss It doesn't, plenty of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ which are not onto and which fix the algebraic numbers.

Comment: @ancientmathematician In that case, there are endomorphisms fixing $F$, without being automorphisms, for which the theorem remains valid?

Comment: Yes, what the OP says is quite right, endomorphisms permute the roots of algebraic equations.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I learned something I would probably have known years ago. Thanks.